# Help with content structure of a typical art gallery website

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

As a way of learning a bit more about how Drupal 7 works, I'm trying to replicate the features of a local art gallery website. I'm having a few problems setting up the content types so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I want to get all the content correctly configured and stored so I can then play around with Views and different ways of presenting that content. Here's what I've come up with having broken down the different types of data:

- ARTIST will have one name, a bio and a website
- ARTWORK will be associated with one artist only, will have a title, may or may not belong to a SERIES, will also have dimensions, an image, a year of creation, and will have the material used to create the artwork (term reference to a taxonomy vocabulary with terms such as "oil on canvas", "photograph", "mixed media" etc)
- SERIES will be associated with one artist only.

So I've set up my content types. Well, the Artist and Artwork ones anyway, but how do I link them? I think I'm supposed to set up Artist as a taxonomy vocabulary, and list the Artist names as terms, and then when creating the content type Artwork have a term reference to it. This is OK but I don't want to have to manually add the term to the vocabulary each time a new content type Artist is created. So I guess what I'm asking is two questions:

1. Is my approach completely wrong? If so, please guide me in the correct direction!
2. If it's not wrong, is there some way to automatically generate the terms of the vocabulary Artist based on the Artist name? So when new Artist content is created, the term is automatically added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is often solved using the Node Reference URL Widget. Here is a video podcast on [Node References](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37) and [another on how to create a gallery](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach).

You should use taxonomy to categorize the different series. Use Views to show the series will take a node reference relationship as an argument as well as the taxonomy id of the series.

Comment: Thanks Adam S: Node References was what I needed. Once I created the node reference from artwork to an artist I managed to create a View which displayed each artwork image alongside the artist's short bio, really just as a way of testing out if the View had connected the two entities.